# Java - Fill Array With Characters From String

Tags: java, arrays, string, character

I want to fill an unknown length of string, split it into character and put it into an array, repeating this process until the array is full. This is a multidimensional array I'm using.

```
    key = input from user as string (length is unknown)
    int[][] fullKey = new int[128][2];
    do {
        for (int ii = 0; ii < key.length(); ii++) {
            fullKey[i][0] = key.charAt(ii);
            i++;
        }
    } while (fullKey[encoding][0] == null);
```

I know that int is primitive so can't be null but it's just to try and explain what I'm attempting to do

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you want to ignore space?

Comment: No with all characters including spaces

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does the below code fit with your requirement?

```
String key = "string";
int row = 2;
int col = 128;
int[][] fullKey = new int[row][col];
int counter=0;

for (int i = 0; i < col; i++) {
    fullKey[0][i] = key.charAt(counter);
    counter = (counter==key.length()-1) ? 0 : (counter+1);
}
```

Comment: Not really sorry this fills the array with 3 characters and then nothing, I want to fill 1 dimension of a two dimensional array with `int` s representing the characters so if the string was `string` so then: `array[0][0] = "s"; array[1][0] = "t"; .......  array[6][0] = "s"; ....... array[17][0] = "g"; that sort of thing? @Kartic

Comment: I have updated my answer. Hopefully I've understood you correctly this time.

Comment: That worked perfectly! Thank you so much, you've no idea how long I've been trying to get my head around it @Kartic

Comment: :) Great to know it helped